# 13.04 Ethernet Adapter not connecting (AR8161)

Tags: networking, drivers, 13.04, atheros

I had the same problem under 12.10 where my Atheros AR8161 wouldn't even show up under the network options. The device does show up in 13.04 as the name "Wired connection 1" When I try to connect to this device, though, it just times out. Under 12.10, I installed the compact-wireless alx driver and everything was fixed. But I am unable to install it in 13.04. Here are a few console outputs for you--if you need more information, please ask--thank you.

lspci

```
brett@brett-pc:~$ lspci | grep Ethernet
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 08)
```

ifconfig

```
brett@brett-pc:~$ ifconfig

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c8:60:00:9a:11:0e  
      inet6 addr: fe80::ca60:ff:fe9a:110e/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:148 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:177 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:13354 (13.3 KB)  TX bytes:38207 (38.2 KB)
      Interrupt:16 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:7073 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:7073 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:582967 (582.9 KB)  TX bytes:582967 (582.9 KB)
```

Edit:
Here's the [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226299/help-with-internet-on-ubuntu-12-10) to my last thread when I was having troubles with 12.10. Maybe this'll spark some interest in this thread."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same network card on my machine,I was able to get it up and running by downloading the source code for the driver (from its homepage at the Linux Foundation) and compiling it:

```
wget -O- https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2013/03/28/compat-drivers-2013-03-28-5-u.tar.gz | tar xz
cd compat-drivers-2013-03-28-5-u/
./scripts/driver-select alx
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -r alx && sudo modprobe alx
```

If that works and you'd like to make the change permanent, you'll want to update the initramfs image with the new driver:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Comment: That's basically what I did. Of course, I didn't have internet, so I wasn't able to wget. I downloaded the source with my laptop and then transferred using USB. Anyway, thank you for the help!